# How to call web service async using TPL

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am writing a WCF(C#4, VS2010) that calls 4 different web-services, do business logic and converts them to application entities. These ws calls,buss logic & entity transformation are independent of each other. Avg response time is around ~4Sec.

Doing the exact above asynchronously using TPL did not help(in reducing the response time, infact id is up by ~100ms); Pseudo code below:

```
Task<Plan> planAsync = Task<Plan>.Factory.StartNew(() => return CallSvcAndGetPlanEntity()); 
Task<Claim> claimAsync = Task<Claim>.Factory.StartNew(() => return CallSvcAndGetClaimEntity()); 
Task<Account> accounAsync = Task<Account>.Factory.StartNew(() => return CallSvcAndGetAccountEntity()); 

//Some business logic here in loop.

Task.WaitAll(planAsync, claimAsync, accountAsync);

Plan p = planAsync.Result;
```

**UPDATE:** 
I introduced a Thread.Sleep of 2Sec at each of the above CallSvc() methods. 
Async method resp time is still 4.1 Sec
Linear method resp time is up to ~7 Sec.

Am i missing something?
What is best way to call WS & do business logic asynchronously?

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` means that execution on the main thread won't continue until all tasks return, so you're limited by the longest running of the calls. Are you saying the average response time of these three calls run synchronously is four seconds and that the run time using the TPL is 4.1 seconds? If that's the case, it's likely that one of the three calls dominates the run time of the others, and using the TPL is introducing overhead but not buying you any savings since only one of the calls ever actually has significant wait time.

Comment: Are all those calls to the same server? Maybe you're limited by [`DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx).

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - Your right. Its up to 4.1S. I have updated my pseudo code. It has a business logic between Task<Account>.Factory.StartNew ans Task.WaitAll(). What are the other options available?

Comment: @svick - No, they are not to the same server.

Comment: if you run these one-by-one, without TPL, what is the longest running time?

Comment: @christiandev - ~4Sec.

Comment: So, in this scenario, ~4 seconds is the best you can hope for.  If you summed up the three calls e.g. 1st call = 2 s, 2nd call = 3 s, and 3rd call = 4 s, thats a total of ~9s.  So, by using the TPL approach, you are saving time.